# re.search to fetch all subblocks

Tags: python, regex, search

I'm facing a problem with regex for a block. I am trying to match a value inside the block. When I use re.search to match all the instances in interface block every time it ends with "instance 3". 

How do I fetch all the instance lines and values inside that block?

Code:

```
for instance in serviceList:
   serviceData = re.search('('+instance+'.*?\n)+\sinstance',block,re.DOTALL)
```

Input:

```
interface
 description 
 mtu 1992
 instance 1
  description OMCH Global Table 
  encapsulation dot1q 1100 second-dot1q 101
 !
 instance 2
  description UNENCRYPT
  bridge-domain 132
 !
 instance 3
  description ENCRYPT
 !
 instance 4
  description TEF
 !
!
```

Comment: What is `serviceList` please share it exactly

Comment: Block contains the value from one interface to another, 
ServiceList is a list of instance which I am taking from the block.
[' instance 1', ' instance 2', ' instance 3', ' instance 4']

Comment: What exactly are you trying to match from the input example above?

Answer (score 0):

```
extract = re.search("instance \d+.*!", block, re.DOTALL).group().split("instance")

for i, j in enumerate(extract):
    if j:
        print("instance" + j)
        print('**' * 10)
```

Output

```
instance 1
  description OMCH Global Table 
  encapsulation dot1q 1100 second-dot1q 101
 !

********************
instance 2
  description UNENCRYPT
  bridge-domain 132
 !

********************
instance 3
  description ENCRYPT
 !

********************
instance 4
  description TEF
 !
!
********************
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you for your time in replying back. I tried this and it's fetching only first instance from the block and jumping to another block their again its searching for instance there. In other words, it's not going to every instance in one block, only the first instance its taking.

Comment: Can u add expected output to your question.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work for the 4th instance because you expect the regex to match an instance at the end as well. The last (4th) instance does not end with "instance".

If you use the `!` as a delimiter then you could do something like this -

```
import re
my_re = r'(?P<instance_id>instance\s\d+)(?P<contents>[^!]*)'
my_input = '''
interface
 description
 mtu 1992
 instance 1
  description OMCH Global Table
  encapsulation dot1q 1100 second-dot1q 101
 !
 instance 2
  description UNENCRYPT
  bridge-domain 132
 !
 instance 3
  description ENCRYPT
 !
 instance 4
  description TEF
 !
!
'''

# create a map of instance id to contents
instance_to_contents = {}
for instance_id, contents in re.findall(my_re, my_input, flags=re.DOTALL):
    instance_to_contents[instance_id] = contents


serviceList = ['instance 1', 'instance 2', 'instance 3', 'instance 4']
# look them up
for instance in serviceList:
    print(instance_to_contents[instance])
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to create a map in the beginning for all of them (if the input is too large and you just need to search for a few instances), you can create the regex in the for loop

```
serviceList = ['instance 1', 'instance 2', 'instance 3', 'instance 4']
# look them up
for instance in serviceList:
    my_re = instance + '(?P<contents>[^!]*)'
    print(re.findall(my_re, my_input, flags=re.DOTALL))
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you for your reply. I tried with 2nd option it's almost working but once it searches all the instance in the first interface block it goes to next and goes on. But once it completes with all the block its again going to first block alone and fetching the instance. Any idea why this happening? Or how to break once it completes with all the block?@algrebe

Comment: @algrebe slightly modified the above pattern ```"(instance\s\d+)([^!]*)"```, getting same output what was the intention in adding ```Named capturing group```

Comment: @Suman - I'm not able to understand what you're asking. Could you update your question with what you tried and what you observe? That may help me figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @Sushanth no reason, it's just a habit of mine. It can be removed.